# react@unknown can't be resolved to a satisfying range

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to create a new React app project using `npx create-react-app my-first-react-app`

I am getting an error -

```
$ npx create-react-app my-first-react-app
npx: installed 67 in 43.776s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\myid\my-first-react-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

➤ BR0027: react@unknown can't be resolved to a satisfying range
➤ BR0027: react-dom@unknown can't be resolved to a satisfying range
➤ BR0027: react-scripts@unknown can't be resolved to a satisfying range
➤ BR0027: cra-template@unknown can't be resolved to a satisfying range
➤ Errors happened when preparing the environment required to run this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd C:\Users\myid\my-first-react-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

I have created .npmrc file in C:\Users\myid\ and declared registry path as the packages comes from our internal organisation repository.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

npm version 6.14.6,
node version 12.18.3

Comment: This might help `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Thank you @Davit I did `npm cache clean --force` and then `npx create-react-app my-first-react-apl`. It's same error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like yarn is causing issue for me. I followed below steps and that did the trick.

```
npm uninstall –g yarn

npm cache clean –force

npx create-react-app my-app
```